# C++ one instance of dynamic library for two seperate programs

Tags: c++, dll

*This question isn't really specific, but more general.*

So let's say I have program A and program B which both use the same dynamic library for example apple.dll. And both programs would use the **same instance of the dynamic library** so changes made with one program in the .dll would also be seen by the other program. So when for example I add two apples in program A, then if I get apples in program B it should return 2.

*See illustration below*

[image: illustration]

So my question is how to achieve this behavior (if it is even possible) and if one solution is cross platform.

Comment: What changes could either program make to the .dll?

Comment: @paolo Well for example the variable apple as seen in the in the illustration can be change with function by both programs.

Comment: What if a third or tenth program starts using the dll? What if you have two separate sets of programs? Please describe the intended behaviour.

Comment: The picture is not really readable for me. However (I may be wrong on this) isn't the ".dll memory", including its global variables, owned by the program's process?

Comment: @paolo Oh sorry should have made it in higher resolution. I know it is owned by the programs process normally, but I want to know if there is way around this.

Comment: Firstly, there is nothing in C++ itself that allows you to do that. However, you may be able to use shared memory, which every OS out there supports, Windows included. Use that as a search term, I believe there even is something in Boost, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global variable in shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695700/global-variable-in-shared-library)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you. What you suggested may be the only real solution as when I was searching I also found only this.

Comment: @Lala5th not really